# Spatial Interpolation Methods like PRISM

Tags: python, r, interpolation, software-recommendations, matlab

I am looking for some kind of software (free software) that allows me to make an interpolation like [PRISM](http://prism.oregonstate.edu/) software.

The interpolation used in PRISM is a

> *local regression and accounts for spatially varying elevation relationships; also accounts for effectiveness of terrain as barriers, terrain-induced climate transitions, cold air drainage and inversions, and coastal effects*

What I am aiming to interpolate are climate time-series datasets.

Comment: PRISM is highly specialized.  It is maintained by a group that appears dedicated to providing its *output* but not the software itself, which is evolving.  Therefore I doubt you will find anything like this in free software unless you can get the original (or can port the source of the original, which started out as an ArcView 3 application).  These researchers do invite interested parties to contact them: visit http://prism.oregonstate.edu/about_us.phtml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you've tagged R in your question I'd take a look at the [CRAN Spatial View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html) and the [gstat](http://www.gstat.org/index.html) package in particular. Not sure if it has the exact PRISM interpolation method, but it would certainly be a good place to start.

Alternately you could look into the SciPy [interpolation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) and [ndimage](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/ndimage.html) subpackages if you'd prefer to work in Python.